# How to create a Toast Notification (with Buttons!) using win32api?

Tags: python, windows, toast, pywin32, win32gui

I've been using the [win10toast library](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/master/win10toast/__init__.py) (link to the **init** file that I'm trying to modify) for a while now, and I have a question:

How could I modify the module to have a toast notification with two buttons kinda [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/images/adaptivetoasts-structure.jpg) with the win32gui, win32api, win32con libs?

I've been playing around with the init code, trying to add a child to `self.hwnd = CreateWindow(...)` around line 83 like this:

```
class ToastNotifier(object):

....

    style = WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU
            styleButton = WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON

            self.hwnd = CreateWindow(self.classAtom, "Taskbar", style,
                                     0, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                     CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                     0, 0, self.hinst, None)

           """ self.hwndButton = CreateWindow("Button", "OK", styleButton,
                                     0, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                     CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                     self.hwnd, None, 0, None)"""

            self.hwndButton = CreateWindow("Button",  # Predefined class; Unicode assumed
                                        "OK",      # Button text
                                        styleButton,  # Styles
                                        0,         #// x position
                                        0,         #// y position
                                        35,        #// Button width
                                        35,        #// Button height
                                        self.hwnd,     #// Parent window
                                        None,       #// No menu.
                                        0,
                                        None)

....
```

but it doesn't work [the way I want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmpQk.png) (The *'1', '2'* Toast notification should have the button OK, not display it on a separate window).

I contacted the module's author be he didn't know how to do it. I'm still trying to learn python, and I don't know much about **win32api**. Any tip? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, and you may have solved it or not, but I'm pretty sure you are on the right track, I dug into the win32gui library for python, and when I looked at the arguments, the first argument requires a unicode literal string, and the word that is really sticking out to me is that it says "unicode assumed",and I believe we can just avoid that assumption by passing it a unicode string literal as follows `u"String"`. Somehow, I feel like the **parent-child relation** here is causing an issue as well, will update when I find more.

> An application that needs to logically divide its main window should
> do so in the window procedure of the main window rather than by using
> child windows.

I'm not well versed on how this is achievable, but I'm sure there is a way.

- [Microsoft Documentation for Toasts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts#buttons)
- [Microsoft Documentation for Win32Gui buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-button)